# Syntax Errors with Custom MVC3 Helper

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to build a custom HTML helper.  Following several tutorials, my code is -

```
namespace System.Web.Mvc.Html 
{
    using System;
    using System.Web.Mvc;
    public static class HtmlHelpers
    {
        public static string BuildJsonPrototype(this HtmlHelper helper, string targetName)
        {
            var d = BuildJsonModel.Build( typeof(Int32), targetName);
            return d;
        }
    }
}
```

In my Razor view, the code is -

```
@using System.Web.Mvc.Html    
@Html.BuildJsonModel( "test")
```

When I try to run this, I'm getting the following compiler error -

```
Compiler Error Message: CS1061: 'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper<AutoBind.Models.ComplexModel>'
does not contain a definition for 'BuildJsonModel' and no extension method
'BuildJsonModel' accepting a first argument of type
'System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper <AutoBind.Models.ComplexModel>' could be found
(are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Any suggestions as to what my syntax error is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code suggests the helper is called 'BuildJsonPrototype' and yet in your markup you are using 'BuildJsonModel'? Is that the problem?

Comment: It is always the obvious things that you cannot see.  Thanks.

Comment: No problem - we've all been there far too many times before :)